# excel index and match function

Tags: vba, excel, match

I am having a situation like this:

```
  | A | B
1 | 1 | Z
2 | 2 | Z
3 | 3 | X
```

and cell `C3` is `Z` (Z is a date)

I want a formula to display when the value in `C3` is `Z`, say in cell `D1` should display `1 2` (separated by space or comma). The formula should compare `C3` with `B1`,`B2` and `B3` and then display text resembling to `A1`,`A2` and `A3`. I am able to use index and match, like

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(C3,B1:B3))
```

but this gives only one result. I.e. of cell `A1`, with regards of `B1`, I want cell value from `A2` as well in one single cell.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339316/concatenate-values-based-on-criteria/34341543#34341543) are some work arounds that  may be of interest.

Comment: Or [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it as a plain formula, you only can chain up all parts like this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A1=C3," "&B1&" ","")&IF(A2=C3," "&B2&" ","")&IF(A3=C3," "&B3&" ",""),"  ",", "))
```

But that is not flexible in any way. So either create a UDF to chain up arrays or make it to directly output it the way you want it.