# How to lookup a value in a table and then return multiple values for when the condition is true?

Tags: excel

I have been trying to work with the LOOKUP, LOOKUPROW, LOOKUPCOLUMN (don't know if this is the right word in english excel) to find multiple values that are correct and then return the values in another cell. For example:

```
col A       Col B       Col C
Charlie    123 45      Stockholm
Dennis     123 46      Stockholm
Jonas      123 45      Stockholm
```

I would like to in a cell where i put in 123 45, then i would like a formula that looks in to the columns A, B and find "123 45" and then returns the name "Charlie" and "Jonas". Right now when using Lookup, i only get the last name (Jonas"). Anyone know how to do this?

Best regards

AgatonSaxx

Comment: See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952). That is for a two-column match but you would just have to reduce it to a one column match.

Comment: As you will see in @Jeeped's linked answer, this cannot be done cleanly in a single cell - see a couple of ways to do this (with either a helper column or a fairly obtuse single-cell formula) here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112330/5090027.

Comment: After a reread of your question, I'm going to switch gears a recommend a UDF. See [Concatenate cell data into another data if values matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches/32110527#32110527).

Comment: Thanks Jeeped your solution worked just fine, thanks everyone else for your answers!