# vlookup two difference data corresponding to two non-adjacent fields

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do a VLOOKUP in the "No"
get the value no"201" where the "no" and "box" from the Purchases sheet match

Screenshot
[image]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$B100,MATCH(1,($A2:$A100=$H1)*($E2:$E100=I$1),0),3),"NONO")
```

can have another option better than VLOOKUP, that's fine too. Thanks!

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula. This formula will filter all data what you will put in `I1` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$25,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$25=$I$1,ROW($A$1:$A$25)),ROWS($A$1:$A1)),COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)),"")
```

As it is a array formula, Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Sample Screenshot]

After putting formula in `G4` cell (As my screenshot) drag and fill right and down as you need.

Comment: sorry i use no 201 and drag it and fill right down
the ask is

202 Orange apple apple ok4
no thing
no thing
no thing

Comment: Do you press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after entering formula?

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas² and the cyclic processing produced by functions like the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) produce calculation lag. The ranges they reference should be kept to a minimum number of rows. It is time consuming to maintain a minimum number of relevant rows on data that receives frequent additions and deletions.

The following formula looks much more complicated but it dynamically tracks the exact number of rows in the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)'s *array*. To simplify the formula, I've allowed one extra row; that being row 1 containing the column header labels.

In I10 as a standard formula,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A )))/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))=$H10), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill right and down.

For your string concatenation. I plucked this VBA User Defined Function³ (aka UDF) from [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches/32110527#32110527) to a similar problem.

```
Public Function conditional_concat_strs(rSTRs As Range, rCRITs As Range, rCRIT As Range, Optional sDELIM As String = ", ")
    Dim c As Long, sTMP As String

    Set rSTRs = Intersect(rSTRs, rSTRs.Parent.UsedRange)
    Set rCRITs = Intersect(rCRITs, rCRITs.Parent.UsedRange)

    Set rSTRs = rSTRs.Cells(1, 1).Resize(rCRITs.Rows.Count, rCRITs.Columns.Count)
    For c = 1 To rCRITs.Cells.Count
        If rCRITs(c).Value2 = rCRIT Then _
            sTMP = sTMP & rSTRs(c).Value & sDELIM
    Next c
    conditional_concat_strs = Left(sTMP, Application.Max(Len(sTMP) - Len(sDELIM), 0))
End Function
```

In I2 as,

```
=conditional_concat_strs(E:E,A:A, I1)
```

The full column references are truncated at the extents of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). There is no calculation penalty for using them.

[image: conditonal_concat]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

² <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

³ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>