# how do i return the field of a specific cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, field

I would ideally like to return a list of the fields of the cells in a row that are greater than zero. If not a list, then just the field of the maximum of these cells.

Comment: Have a look at [Concatenate cell data into another data if values matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches/32110527#32110527) and rework it for your own purposes.

Comment: Unless the field list is static that you can conditionally concatenate all of them in a long formula, you will run into Excel's inability to concatenate items in an array. Exception is Excel 365 that has the `TEXTJOIN()` function. Unless you have this version, you will have to contemplate a VBA solution. Also please provide sample data, code you have tried so far and expected results sample. Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: If you want just the field of a max value, perhaps look into Index/Match, using `Max()` for the match?

Comment: Yes, sorry, by field I mean column label.

Comment: Thank you nabayly. I am using 2013 I think, but not 365. I can see if I can provide data

Comment: Thanks jeeped, I will give I a go.